# How do I avoid infinite loops while calculating a parameterized type's supertypes?

Tags: java, jls

(This is not a basic recursion question, nor is it a question about how to work with `ParameterizedType`. This is a question concerning the application of some algorithms in the Java Language Specification to types of various kinds.)

[The Java Language Specification, §4.10.2, says what a parameterized type's *direct supertypes* are](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2).  (This also involves [notions of type containment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1) and [capture conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10); more below.)

There are two cases:

1. The parameterized type has no wildcard type arguments.
2. The parameterized type has at least one wildcard type argument.

In Case 1, to get a parameterized type's direct supertypes, you proceed (among other paths) by figuring out [what types contain the parameterized type's type arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1).  (These amount to a bunch of wildcards that can contain the argument itself, along with the argument itself.  So in `Iterable<Object>`, `Object`'s containing types are `?`, `? super Object` and `Object` itself.)

So your wildcard-free parameterized type's direct supertypes end up being itself and a bunch of wildcarded flavors of it.

In Case 2, the first thing you do to your wildcard-containing parameterized type is [apply capture conversion to it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10) and you end up with a wildcard-free parameterized type suitable for running through Case 1.

Now, to get *all* supertypes of any type, not just the direct ones, you [apply the direct supertype relation reflexively and transitively to it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10).

With what I've outlined above, in the case of parameterized types, doesn't this result in an infinite loop, even if you keep track of types you've already "seen" as you ordinarily do when "doing recursion" (i.e. in a set of some kind)?

That is: suppose you're trying to get *all* supertypes, not just the direct ones, of `Iterable<?>`:

- You start by finding its direct supertypes.

  - By definition you enter Case 2 because the type is parameterized with a wildcard.
  - You apply capture conversion so you can enter Case 1.
  - Now you are working with `Iterable<CAP extends Object>` as if that were the type you had been working with all along.
  - You enter Case 1 because it doesn't have any wildcards in it.
  - You figure out what the containing types of `CAP extends Object` are.

    - They are ([§5.1.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10)):

      - `?`
      - `? extends CAP extends Object`
      - `? super CAP extends Object`
      - `CAP extends Object`
  - So the direct supertypes of the parameterized type `Iterable<?>` are:

    - `Iterable` (the raw type)
    - `Object` (because `Iterable` is an interface with no direct superinterfaces)
    - `Iterable<?>` (containing type)
    - `Iterable<? extends CAP extends Object>` (containing type)
    - `Iterable<? super CAP extends Object>` (containing type)
    - `Iterable<CAP extends Object` (containing type)
- Now run the direct supertype relation over these (the "transitive" part)
- You get an infinite loop because one of the containing types is `Iterable<? extends CAP extends Object>` (applying capture conversion to that results in `Iterable<CAP extends CAP extends Object>`, so one of its supertypes is `Iterable<? extends CAP extends CAP...` you get the idea).

What is the proper way of breaking this loop, or am I overlooking some condition somewhere that says, effectively, the containing types of a fresh type variable are simply itself?

Comment: It looks like [javac manually breaks the loop](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/0f2113cee79b9645105b4753c7d7eacb83b872c2/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Types.java#L1587).

Comment: It is also nice to know [that I am not insane](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8078016).